# How to create SublimeText like build files in notepad++?

Tags: java, sublimetext2, notepad++, text-editor

is such option available in notepad++ ?

for example , my custom java build in SublimeText2 is like :

```
{
    "cmd": ["javac","-d","../bin","$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?):([0-9]*):?([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.java"
}
```

and it takes the file i'm working on and compiles it into the bin folder.

**ps:** I'm mainly an eclipse user , i use a text editor for casual stuff or when i'm learning something new.